# Unable to load the logo of Android app

Tags: android, macos, apk

I'm using Mac OS to develop an Android app. I'm unable to generate the apk file.

The error:

> Error:(14) Error: Unexpected resource reference type; expected value of type @string/ [ReferenceType]

My code in XML document:

```
<string name="icon_name">@mipmap/ic_lau_spt</string>
```

Why is the error generated?

Answer (score 4):

The error is generated because your xml item is a string

```
<string name="icon_name">@mipmap/ic_lau_spt</string>
   ^                                           ^
```

and your reference is an resource/image

If you want to load it as the app logo (show this image in the app drawer)
search this

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

in your android manifest and replace the ic_launcher with your image

Comment: what can be put in instead?

Comment: its the application logo.

Comment: Just put `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_lau_spt"` at **<application></application>** in AndroidManifest file.

Comment: just remove "<string name="icon_name">@mipmap/ic_lau_spt</string>" from your strings.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the string tag you can't put resource id. `@mipmap/ic_lau_spt` is a image resource id.

Comment: what resource id can be used?

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml

You define the application icon

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
</application>
```

Comment: just remove "<string name="icon_name">@mipmap/ic_lau_spt</string>" from your strings.xml file your project will compile and run.

Answer (score 1):

in your manifest.xml file inside application tag put

```
<manifest

  <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
  </application>

</manifest>
```